# Get All attributes of a class where there are lists of class c#?

Tags: c#

How can i do to get all attributes of this class

```
public class Data
{
    public Person;
    public List<Nationality> nationality;
    public List<Passport> passport;
    public List<Family> family;
    public List<WK_Permit> Permit;
    public List<Role> role;
}
```

the expected output  is for example

i wan to get something like that "DATA.PERSON.NAME" or "DATA.PASSPORT.NUMBER" or "DATA.ROLES.HOST"...etc so i have to get the class name and the attibuts name

I did this but it doesn't work for class's list

```
 Type parent = typeof(VSM_Data);
            FieldInfo[] children = parent.GetFields();

            for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
            {

                Type child = children[i].FieldType;

                var columnnamesChild = from t in child.GetProperties() select t.Name;
                foreach (var item in columnnamesChild)
                {
                    DragAndDrop FundDragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
                    FundDragAndDrop.TITLE = item;
                    FundDragAndDrop.adresse = "{{PERSON." + children[i].Name.ToUpper() + "." + item.ToUpper() + "}}";
                    FundList.Add(FundDragAndDrop);

                }
```

Comment: What do you meant by attribute name? What is the expected output?

Comment: there is no attributes here

Comment: he probably mean members guys common.. little judgement

Comment: For example on the table Person there are attributs like NAME, SURNAME..etc

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using [**Reflection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx):

Reflection; for an instance:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
obj.GetType().GetMembers();
```

for a type:

```
typeof(Foo).GetProperties();
typeof(Foo).GetMembers();
```

for example:

```
class Foo {
    public int A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string Member1;
    public int Member2;
}
...
```

For Fields:

```
        foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetFields()) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name);
        }
```

For Properties:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo {A = 1, B = "abc"};
    foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(foo, null));
    }
```

for Members:

```
foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetMembers()) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", prop.Name);
    }
```

Comment: But there is no  property here

Comment: i have given a generic answer, so that it helps every one who comes on this post

Comment: i post for Members as well

Comment: the generic answer will be members as by default  all encapsulated are members by default

Comment: For the posted question, I would suggest you use `GetFields` instead of `GetMembers`. `GetMembers` will retrieve _all_ members, including (but not limited to) constructors (even the implicit default parameterless constructor), the backing methods for property accessors, and methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Data data =  new Data();
            //you can use this for your case 
            var fields = data.GetType().GetFields().Select(f => f.Name);

            foreach (var f in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f);

            }
           Console.WriteLine("===");
            //but if you want a more generic one try this 
            var members = data.GetType().GetMembers().Select(m=>m.Name);
            foreach (var member in members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(member);

            }




        }
```

Comment: no  it will list the  name of your member(property or fields) see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you all public property name

```
Type type = typeof(Data);
foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    string name = property.Name;
```

Comment: you are getting properties, there are no properties in OP class, it has only Members

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I missread is exemple. I thought that he would the properties.

Comment: @user3510152: Use `GetFields` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It ok i find the solution sometime the best way to find the solution is to ask the question and think by your self ;-)

```
Type type = typeof(VSM_Data);
            foreach (var property in type.GetFields())
            {
                FieldInfo[] children = type.GetFields();

                for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
                {

                    Type child = property.FieldType;

                    var columnnamesChild = from t in child.GetFields() select t.Name;
                    foreach (var item in columnnamesChild)
                    {
                        DragAndDrop FundDragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
                        FundDragAndDrop.TITLE = item;
                        FundDragAndDrop.adresse = "{{PERSON." + children[i].Name.ToUpper() + "." + item.ToUpper() + "}}";
                        FundList.Add(FundDragAndDrop);

                    }
                }
            }
```